# Error "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRUEBA'" al invocar dese Java una función de Oracle con parámetros de tipo BOOLEAN

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jdbc

Estoy tratando de llamar a una función de Oracle desde Java, y obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'prueba'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'prueba'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Esta es la forma en la que estoy invocando a la función:

```
String ejecucion = "{ ?=call prueba(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }";

CallableStatement cons = c.ejecutarProcedimiento(ejecucion, 0);  // Aquí invoco al método "precall"
double monto = 0;

cons.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.FLOAT);

// Parametro del procedimiento almacenado
cons.setFloat(2, 2);
cons.setDouble(3, importe);
cons.setDate(4,TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.cabezal.getFechaVencimientoPresentacion()));                                                                                 
 cons.setDate(5,TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.cabezal.getFechaVencmientoPago()));
cons.setDate(6, TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.fechaActual));
cons.setDate(7, TareasGenerales.convertirFecha(Parametros.fechaActual));
cons.setBoolean(8, false);
cons.setInt(9, Integer.valueOf(Parametros.cabezal.getAnioMesDesde()));
cons.setBoolean(10, false);

cons.executeQuery();
```

Esta es la forma en la que está implementada la función:

```sql
declare
 -- Boolean parameters are translated from/to integers: 
 -- 0/1/null <--> false/true/null 
  pa_a boolean := sys.diutil.int_to_bool(:a);
  pa_b boolean := sys.diutil.int_to_bool(:b);
   begin
 -- Call the function
 :result := prueba(c=> :c,
                                       d => :d,
                                       e => :e,
                                       f => :f,
                                       g => :g,
                                       h => :g,
                                       i => i,
                                       j => :j,
                                       k => k);
end;

FUNCTION Prueba(tipo_calc           IN NUMBER,
                    impte           IN NUMBER,
                    f_venc         IN DATE,
                    f_venc_p         DATE,
                    f_pre          IN DATE,
                    f_pa            IN DATE,
                    pa_tiene IN BOOLEAN,
                    pa_anio         IN NUMBER,
                    pa_buen     IN BOOLEAN) RETURN NUMBER;
```

¿Saben cuál puede ser el origen del error?

Comment: Me suena que hay algún problema derivado del uso de parámetros Boolean. Prueba a cambiarlos tanto en Java como en el PL, por char(1) por ejemplo.

Comment: @pablo, gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que no puedo realizar la modificación en PL/SQL, ya que estoy trabajando en un proyecto de automatización de pruebas y no puedo pedirle al desarrollador que haga ese cambio. ¿Sabes cómo puedo hacerlo desde Java?

Comment: ¿Puedes crear funciones PL/SQL nuevas?

Comment: No, no podemos, ya que la base de datos no es nuestra.

Comment: Pues lo siento pero, usando JDBC al menos, no se me ocurre solución sin poder acceder a la BD.

Answer (score 2):

En efecto, como se menciona en los comentarios, los drivers JDBC de Oracle de versiones anteriores a 12.2 no son capaces de manejar el tipo `BOOLEAN`.

[A partir de Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDBC/release-changes.htm#JJDBC29138), parece que sí es posible hacerlo (finalmente).

Pero entre tanto, en vez de recurrir a concatenar los parámetros directamente en la cadena SQL, una forma sencilla de corregir el problema es pasándo un `int` en vez de `boolean` en el código Java, y luego usando una expresión `CASE` en el SQL para convertir el `int` de vuelta a `boolean`:

```
String ejecucion = "{ ?=call prueba(?,?,?,?,?,?,case when ? = 0 then false else true end,?,case when ? = 0 then false else true end) }";

// ....

cons.setInt(8, 0); // 0 => false
// ...
cons.setInt(10, 1); // 1 => true
```

Comment: Gracias! Funciona perfectamente. case when ? = 0 then false else true end.   y luego pasarle un int como mencionas.

Answer (score -1):

Finalmente resolví el problema, pasando los argumentos directamente en el String "ejecución" en lugar de agregarlos luego.

Comment: Esto derrota la idea de usar el statement. El uso ideal es el que indican en la otra respuesta.